# I see this error : Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: swift, xcode

I see this error: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value at the line

```swift
@IBAction func autoplay(_ sender: Any) {
    if UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey:"switchState3") == true {
        player.enableRate = true
        player.rate = UserDefaults.standard.float(forKey:"playSpeed")
        var items : [AVPlayerItem] = []
        for number in myIndex..<arr.count{
            // here I see the error
            let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: String(myIndex)+String(number), withExtension: "mp3")!
            items.append(AVPlayerItem(url: url))
        }
        let queue = AVQueuePlayer(items: items)
        queue.play()
    }
}
```

the edited code is the following:

```
  @IBAction func autoplay(_ sender: Any) {
    if UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey:"switchState3")==true {
        player.enableRate = true
        player.rate = UserDefaults.standard.float(forKey:"playSpeed")
        var items : [AVPlayerItem] = []
        for number in 1..<10{
            let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: String(number), withExtension: "mp3")!
            items.append(AVPlayerItem(url: url))
        }
        let queue = AVQueuePlayer(items: items)
        queue.play()
    }
```

I don't see any error but when I click the button, anything doesn't happen.

When I tried in Xcode console, the code is:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

let arr = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20"]
var items : [AVPlayerItem] = []
for number in 0..<arr.count{
    let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: String(number), withExtension: "mp3")!
    items.append(AVPlayerItem(url: url))
    print(items)
}
```

Comment: where is your myIndex declared?

Comment: it's declared out of class TableViewController: UITableViewController { } I edited it... like the following and there's no any error but when I click the button it anything doesn't happen...

Comment: Are you sure that it gets initialized before accessing it?

Comment: yes! it gets initialized. I realized that the error was because myIndex+arr.count is over the last arr. I edited my code and I don't see any error but anything doesn't happen when I click the button.

Comment: Can you print items array and make sure it is populated?

Comment: Sorry but how do I print it? I tried like this : test.text = String(items) but I see this error: Initializer 'init(_:)' requires that '[_]' conform to 'LosslessStringConvertible'

Comment: Just do like print(items) and check out log in Xcode console.

Comment: I checked out and it's working well in Xcode console.

Comment: What did it print? Did the array has values in it?

Comment: oh, I think I did the wrong. now that I try it again, it shows the error: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: I added the code that I used in Xcode console onto my question.

Comment: In which line did you get exception?

Comment: here : let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: String(number), withExtension: "mp3")!

Comment: next to the line, I can see this error as well: error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0).
The process has been left at the point where it was interrupted, use "thread return -x" to return to the state before expression evaluation.

Comment: Do you have files named "1.mp3", "2.mp3" and so on bundled in your resources?

Comment: wow! it's working now. I didn't put mp3 files in resource. it's weird because it work in Xcode console but it doesn't work in project. in project, I have mp3 files.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever `String(myIndex) + String(number) + ".mp3"` is, it doesn't exist as a file within your application. Can you add `print(\(String(myIndex))\(String(number)).mp3` above the line `let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: /* here I see the error */
String(myIndex)+String(number), withExtension: "mp3")!`? This will let you check the console and see what the value of the problematic `String` you are producing via `String(myIndex)+String(number)` is and you can cross reference this `String` with the mp3 files in your build to ensure you are constructing the `String` correctly.